# join two tables in linq with special conditions

Tags: linq, join, lambda, where-clause, notin

I hope one can help me, I am new in linq,
I have 2 tables name tblcart and tblorderdetail:
I just show some fields in these two tables to show whats my problem:

tblCart:
ID,
CartID,
Barcode,

and tblOrderDetail:
ID,
CartID,
IsCompleted
Barcode

when someone save an order, before he confirms his request,one row temporarily enter into the tblCart,
then if he or she confirms his request another row will be inserted into the tblOrderDetail ,

Now I wanna not to show the rows that is inserted into tblOrderDetailed(showing just temporarily rows which there is in tblCart),

In another words, if there is rows in tblCart with cartID=1 and at the same time there is the same row with CartID= 1 in tblOrderDetail, then I dont want that Row.

All in all, Just the rows that there isnt in tblOrderDetail, and the field to realize this is CartID, 
I should mention that I make Iscompleted=true, and with that either we can exclude the rows we do not want,

I did this:

```
var cartItems = context.tblCarts
    .Join(context.tblSiteOrderDetails, 
        w => w.CartID, 
        orderDetail => orderDetail.cartID,
        (w,orderDetail) => new{w,orderDetail})
    .Where(a=>a.orderDetail.cartID !=a.w.CartID)
    .ToList()
```

however it doesn't work.

one example:

```
tblCart:
ID=1
CartID=1213
Barcode=4567

ID=2
CartID=1214
Barcode=4567

ID=3
CartID=1215
Barcode=6576

tblOrderDetail:
ID=2
CartID=1213
Barcode=4567
IsCompleted=true
```

with these data it should just show the last two Row in tblCart, I mean

```
ID=2
CartID=1214
Barcode=4567

ID=3
CartID=1215
Barcode=6576
```

Comment: can you provide a a few sample rows for each table, and then a sample output from your query using those rows?

Comment: @pquest yup ofcurse

Comment: Please add the model of cart to your question -- specifically, do you have a navigation property on cart to reference the details?

Comment: thaks I found one solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case for `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in sql.

roughly translated this should be something like this in LINQ:

```
var cartItems = context.tblCarts.Where(crt => !context.tblSiteOrderDetails.Any(od => od.CartID == crt.cartID));
```

Comment: Thank you., what I was looking for actually,worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you have a navigation property on cart to reference details (I'll assume it's called `Details`), then:

```
var results=context.tblCarts.Where(c=>!c.Details.Any(d=>d.IsCompleted));
```

Comment: I tested your solution as well, and it was the second solution for me as I had two field to follow my problem,  thank you so much